# Deserializing XML in C# when there is just a single element

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to deserialize the following XML response into a c# object

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
     Error message
  </string>
```

Here is the object I'm trying to deserialize to.  Not quite sure how to make the root element match the `ErrorMessage` property

```
[Serializable]
public class QObject
{
    [XmlElement("string")]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

When I serialize a `QObject` into a string, it looks like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<QObject xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><string>test</string></QObject>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making your class

```
[XmlRoot("string")]
public class QObject
{
    [XmlText]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

The `[XmlText]` attribute is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) and `[XmlRoot]` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).